# Find the z-transform of $n^2 3^n$

Tags: z-transform

I have $n^2 3^n$, and want to find the z-transform of it.

I take

$$n^2 3^n= n\cdot n 3^n$$

and we can see from a z-transform table that

$$3^n \rightarrow\frac{z}{z-3}$$

$$n3^{n-1} \rightarrow\frac{z}{(z-3)^2}$$

$$n \rightarrow\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$$

and these are awfully familiar with the correct [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Z-transform%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%223%5E%28n%29%20n%5E2%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22n%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22z%22):

\begin{equation}
n^2 3^n \rightarrow \frac{3 z (3 + z)}{(z-3)^3}
\end{equation}

An alternative is to use the definition
\begin{equation}
V(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty v(n)z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n^2 3^n z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{n^2 3^n}{ z^{n}}
\end{equation}

But this is not the same as the answer by WA.

How is it calculated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, thanks to some help. The table of transforms states that $nx_n\rightarrow -zX'(z)$.

Putting $x_n=n3^{n}$, which is the function to transform specifically, we use the rule

$na^{n-1}\rightarrow \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ on it.

Re-writing:

$x_n=n3^{n}=3\cdot n3^{n-1}$, we use the z-transform rule given above, and obtain:

$3\cdot n3^{n-1}\rightarrow X(z)=\frac{3z}{(z-3)^2}$.

We then need to find $X'(z)$. So,

$\frac{3z}{(z-3)^2}'= -3\frac{3 + z}{(x-3)^3}$

The first z-transform rule at the top gives then:

\begin{equation}
nx_n=n\cdot n3^{n}\rightarrow -zX'(z)\rightarrow  z\bigg(\frac{9 + 3z)}{(z-3)^3}\bigg)
\end{equation}